# In Ubuntu, how to copy all contents of a folder to another folder?

Tags: ubuntu, zip, wordpress

I want to copy the contents of an unzipped folder, `wordpress/`, to another existing folder.

I tried

```
cp -R wordpress/*.* /my/folder
```

but the sub-folders in `wordpress/` didn't get copied over.

Why not?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try

```
cp -r wordpress/* /my/folder
```

Comment: hm....case senstivity :) what does the -r do?

Comment: This is weird. I just tested ur command line. It also works. According to the manpages, -r Copy file hierarchies and the treatment of special files is implementation-defined. While -R is more versatile.  http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/posix/cp

Comment: MORE PERTINENTLY: There's a different ARGUMENT being provided; wordpress/*.* is NOT the same as wordpress/* - subfolders didn't get copied with *.* because the folder names do not include the character "." in them.

Answer (score 2):

If you have hidden files/directories then you'll need to run the following from inside the source directory

```
tar pcf - .| (cd /path/to/destination; tar pxf -)
```

that will copy all files and folders including ones starting with a . (dot).

If you don't have hidden files/directories that need to be copied then wliao's answer will do.

(edited for clarity)